# Re-declaring variable in multiple for loops - for(var i ...)

Tags: javascript

In the past I used write for loops like this:

```
// Count to 10
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}

var message = "We're done here!";

// Count down by 10's from 100
for(var i = 100; i >= 0; i -= 10) {
    console.log(i);

    if(i === 0) {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

Then, after failing every syntax code checker under the sun and being told not to re-declare variables, I ended up coding like this, using a single `var` statement at the top of each scope:

```
var i,  message = "We're done here!";

// Count to 10
for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}

// Count down by 10's from 100
for(i = 100; i >= 0; i -= 10) {
    console.log(i);

    if(i === 0) {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

Personally, keeping the `var` seems like it would make the code more maintainable, when you don't have to worry whether `i` was declared or not. I've seen similar issues brought up on [multiple `var` statements](http://benalman.com/news/2012/05/multiple-var-statements-javascript/). If the interpreter is simply ignoring the additional declaration, and treating it as an assignment, I don't see why it could be a bad thing.

So, if you ignore all the conventions, and style guides, **can re-declaring `i` in each loop potentially cause any problems, performance or otherwise**?

*(Aside from failing said syntax checkers and Douglas Crockford getting mad at you).*

Comment: It does not cause any run-time problems to have a redeclaration.  All `var` declarations are automatically hoisted to the top of the function scope anyway by the parser so they are all collapsed into one.  Assignments are done in place where they code was written.  Just the declaration is hoisted.  The warning is likely because they want to advise you that this is not a separate and new variable, but the same one that is already in use.  In ES6, you can use `let` which will be scoped to a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, if you ignore all the conventions, and style guides, can
>   re-declaring i in each loop potentially cause any problems,
>   performance or otherwise?

No, it does not cause any problems at run-time or affect performance.

All `var` declarations within a scope are hoisted to the top of the block (before any code runs in that block) so any dups are just combined.  The parser just ignores duplicate declarations.

The only downsides I can think of are that it adds a slight bit more size to the code (extra `var`) vs. combining all the `var` declarations at the top.  But, if you run a minimizer, that extra size should be removed.

The **warning** and **general style recommendation** is likely because a duplicate `var` declaration can lead a reader or coder to accidentally think they are declaring a new, unused local variable when, in fact, that variable is already in use and may already have a value and some other code may already be using that variable.  If you know that is not the case, then it does not harm other than perhaps make it easier for you to accidentally make that mistake.

---

FYI, for a `for` loop, ES6 solves this issue with the `let` declaration which, when used in `for` loop initializer will declare a variable that is uniquely scoped to that `for` loop.

```
// Count to 10
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    // i is scoped to within this loop only
    console.log(i);
}

// Count down by 10's from 100
for (let i = 100; i >= 0; i -= 10) {
    // i is scoped to within this loop only
    console.log(i);

    if(i === 0) {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

---

For my personal style, I find my code more maintainable if I keep the `var` declaration with the `for` loop, even if I am reusing the same variable (easier to move code around and see where the declaration is).  I just find each loop a lot more self contained.  And, I would declare it differently (outside the loop) if I was ever trying to use the loop variable outside of the `for` loop.  Obviously if I'm in an ES6 environment, I will use `let` for a `for` loop variables.

I avoid redeclaring any other variable within a function because it seems like that is more likely a mistake than a purposeful intention and there seems to rarely be a maintenance benefit to redeclaring it.